# Replacing all occurences of text group with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some (HTML) text in a string and in that text there are several occurences of this "Group" `<br><hr/><br>`. The simple regex `(<br><hr\/><br>)` finds the **first** occurence. What I'm looking for is a way to use preg_replace to replace *all* of the occurences with another text.

When I use the regex I have with preg_replace, I just get an empty string - with no errors in my log file.

This preg_replace works for me: `preg_replace('@(<br><hr\/><br>)@', ' *POST* ', $string);`

Comment: Use your regex with `/g` flag to replace all occurrence.

Comment: If it's just a static string, why not use `str_replace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it

```
 $output=preg_replace_callback("#<br><hr\/><br>#",function($matches){print_r($matches[0]."\n");return 'replace Text';},' '.$str.' ');
```

Comment: The answer from @mohammad-mohsenipur works, but the error was all mine :-( In a line depper in the code there was a tiny error!